# How to save a Delaunay triangulation in shapefile with Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, delaunay, triangulation

I have a csv file with coordinates and values for each point.

I have made a Delaunay Triangulation and I save it in .png and .pwg formats, but I also would to save in shapefile format, I try with fiona, with shapefile, scipy... and nothing work.

Any ideas? This is the code for triangulation:

```
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)       
refiner = tri.UniformTriRefiner(triang)
tri_refi, z_test_refi = refiner.refine_field(z, subdiv=3)    

# Plot the triangulation and the high-res iso-contours

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
"""num_of_levels = 20
levels = np.arange(np.amin(z),np.amax(z),(np.amax(z)-np.amin(z))/num_of_levels)
ax.tricontourf(tri_refi, z_test_refi, levels=levels, cmap='jet', shading='gouraud') # 'terrain'
"""
'''ax.tricontour(tri_refi, z_test_refi, levels=levels,
              colors=['0.25', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5'],
              linewidths=[1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])'''
plt.axis('off')
'''fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)'''

filename= col.split(' ')[0].replace('/','')
filename=filename.strip()
diname=fN.replace('/','_').replace(' ','')
if not os.path.exists(diname):
    os.makedirs(diname)

fn = diname + '/' +filename+'.png'
plt.savefig(fn, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0, transparent=True, dpi=300)
write_worldfile(fn,x,y)
```

Comment: do you want a shapefile or a picture of your graph?

Comment: There are many helpful webpages and videos using GDAL to polygonize a raster layer.  See here for the basic code:  https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html